# Are chained maps optimized by compiler?

Tags: scala, compiler-optimization

Scala has an amazing way of converting a collection into another collection using `map` construct.

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
l.map(_*_)
```

will return the squares of the elements in list `l`

I come across various instances where multiple maps are chained together say,

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val res = l.map(_ * _).map(_ + 1).filter(_ < 3)
```

What i believe happens underneath is equivalent to something below.

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val l1 = l.map(_*_)
val l2 = l1.map(_ + 1)
val res = l2.filter(_ < 3)
```

creating `l1` and `l2` might cause memory issues if the collection is too big.
To tackle this problem, does Scala compiler have any optimizations?

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val res = l1.map( _*_ + 1).filter(_ < 3)
```

in general if `f`, `g`, `h` are functions

```
val l = List(/*something*/)
val res = l.map(f(_)).map(g(_)).map(h(_))
```

can be converted into

```
val res = l.map(f _ andThen g _ andThen h _)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because this would require the compiler to know about the semantics of `map` and treat the standard library classes which implement it specially (since nobody stops you from writing a class where this doesn't hold). There is a [research proposal](http://wiki.epfl.ch/edicpublic/documents/Candidacy%20exam/PR14Petrashko.pdf) which might end up implementing this... eventually.

There is also [Scala-Blitz](https://scala-blitz.github.io/) which optimizes some collection operations, but fusion and deforestation are listed as future work in [this presentation](https://scala-blitz.github.io/talks/scaladays2014-final.pdf) and I don't think they are implemented yet.

As Steve Waldman's answer says, using `Stream` (or, better yet, `Iterator`) can help, but it won't eliminate the intermediate collections completely.

Answer (score 4):

Scala offers `Stream`, which is a lazy ordered collection.

```
val s = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4)

// note i've changed your sequence of transformations
// a bit, so that it compiles and yields more than one result
val res = s.map(i => i * i).map(_ + 1).filter(_ < 11)
```

`res` is now a `Stream`. No actual evaluation has been performed yet, no blocks of memory related to the size of `s` have been used.

If you intend to use the elements of `res` one at a time, no more work is required. You can use `res` in a for statement or comprehension directly, for example.

```
for ( elem <- res ) println( s"A value is ${elem}" )
```

If you want `res` as a `List`, you can just call `.toList` at the end of the sequence of transformations. Instead of the above, use

```
val res = s.map(i => i * i).map(_ + 1).filter(_ < 11).toList
```

`s` will only be traversed once in creating the new `List`.

Comment: You can also use `view` on the list to make it lazily evaluated. Like this: `val res = l.view.map(_ * _).map(_ + 1).filter(_ < 3).force`

Comment: @SteveWaldman agreed using streams is a lazy way of doing it. But even then, when you would chain maps and evaluate them when needed, multiple intermediate streams would still get generated. So space needed for `l.map(_ * _ + 1).filter( _ < 3)` will be less than `l.map(_ * _).map( _ + 1).filter(_ < 3)`

Comment: @ApoorvIngle Not really, because each element is generated one at a time. There are no intermediate streams. Sure, in some trivial way, the implementation of a three-transformation chain will use more space than a two transformation chain. But you only need that space once, not `n` times (for an `n` element list) if you build lazily. You transform an element thru the full chain, then reuse the same stack space to transform the next. Not lazily, you build multiple full lists on the heap, a full iteration for each step, then garbage collect them.

Comment: @SteveWaldman yes, you are right about that. But JVM being non-deterministic for its garbage collection, we might still end up utilizing the same amount of space we would have if we used Lists. What we should be comparing is the performance of same collections over chained maps. Comparing Streams with List is like comparing apples to organges in this case.